# Animation (timeline) playing issue

Tags: javafx-8

I have created a timeline object which shall make a label blink by alternating its visibleProperty, but this does not work. The timeline should start playing when you press the button in my code example. Can anyone please help me with the issue?

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Label lbl = new Label("label");
    Button btn = new Button("play");

    btn.setOnAction(event -> {
        //create timeline
        KeyValue keyValue = new KeyValue(lbl.visibleProperty(), false);
        KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.5), keyValue);
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(keyFrame);
        timeline.setCycleCount(6);
        timeline.setAutoReverse(true);
        timeline.play();
    });
    VBox pane = new VBox(lbl, btn);
    pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    Scene sc = new Scene(pane, 200, 200);
    primaryStage.setScene(sc);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interpolating `Boolean` is problematic, since the animation jumps to the end result, if the animation reached a point where the time difference to the end is so small it's considered to be zero. This results in a problem in this case.

You could of course work with 3 `KeyFrame`s here, but the much simpler approach would be to simply use an `EventHandler` to negate the `visible` property every time it's executed:

```
btn.setOnAction(event -> {
    // create timeline
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.25), evt -> {
        lbl.setVisible(!lbl.isVisible());
    }));
    timeline.setCycleCount(6);
    timeline.play();
});
```